# Kubernetes services with spec type ClusterIP and spec type Nodeport

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I m trying to create a service where there is a connection between the pods via a service with the `spec type: ClusterIP`and now I want to expose this application to my browser with the `spec type: NodePort` However I m not able to add the type NodePort to the existing service.yaml. How do I specify the second specs in the same service for the same application?

app1-->connects to app2(db via ClusterIP: port 1521)
app1-->expose to ingress to access it from my browser

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"name":"partner-service","namespace":"default"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":1521,"protocol":"TCP","targetPort":1521}]}}
  creationTimestamp: "2021-03-08T14:32:02Z"
  labels:
    app: partner-db
  name: partner-service
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "12574"
  uid: b5106bef-a292-4a16-aafc-9676a81cd763
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.96.122.33
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.96.122.33
  ports:
  - port: 1521
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1521
  selector:
    app: partner-db
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

This throws error that ClusterIp is required. Is it possible to have 2 types of connections in the same service?

I also tried `k expose deployment partner-as --type=NodePort --ports=8080` but with the error service already exists

This runs on a vagrant VM where minikube is installed

As per the comment added a second service.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-03-09T09:28:00Z"
  labels:
    app: partner-as
  name: service-as
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "16889"
  uid: bed7ab44-c350-45e6-87c4-8aac037740c3
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.104.102.177
  clusterIPs:
  - 10.104.102.177
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 30029
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8080
  selector:
    app: partner-as
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: NodePort
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

and my ingress.yaml

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-as
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - host: partner.info
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /partner
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service-as
                port:
                  number: 8080
```

Added partner.info in my etc hosts in the vagrant vm.

Still the IP is not accessible from ym local machine.(so no access from brwoser)

Describe my service-as

```
Name:                     service-as
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   app=partner-as
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 app=partner-as
Type:                     NodePort
IP Families:              <none>
IP:                       10.104.102.177
IPs:                      10.104.102.177
Port:                     <unset>  8080/TCP
TargetPort:               8080/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  30029/TCP
Endpoints:                172.17.0.5:8080
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

Comment: you can use to two type of service for single service. what you can do is to just simple name of service keep lable and everything smae

Comment: does that mean i not just add specs, but altogether create a new service within the same file?

Comment: depends on the requirement if you just want a node port service, delete the existing one and create a new service as a node port if you want both type of service apply the above yaml.

Comment: are you mapping which IP in /etc/host ? with partner.info ? ClusterIP ? or ingress controller IP ?

Comment: ClusterIP is internal stuff that is only accessible internally you can't access it outside of Kubernetes cluster.

Comment: Of accessing the service you can use command port-forward for part time or else expose your serivce as NodePort of Loadbalancer so that you can access service from browser.

Comment: Actually the partner.info is with the minikube IP. I made a mistake when typing the comment

Comment: With ClusterIP you can not access the service from Browser it can be only useful for internall communication like from app1 to app2 but can't accesible from outside browser.

Comment: That's weird. checked by portforward command ? are you getting output on broser ?

Comment: `kubectl port-forward svc/service-as 8080` and open `localhost:8080` in your browser.

Comment: i did this already. But i think it still doesnt come out of my vagrant vm. the kubernetes runs inside the minikube

Comment: hope your application is running inside pod and ready to handle traffic ideally it should be shwing output.

Comment: yes the application is running. i can curl `partner.info/partner` and it gives me output. i have also added my service-as description

Comment: Okay so curl is working then where you got stuck ?.

Comment: curl from my minikube is working.. but not from my browser after port forwarding.

Comment: as you are running vgrant may be due to that issue is there.

Comment: https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/none/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229681/discussion-between-vini-and-harsh-manvar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create **two services** with a different name but just keep the same **selector**

To a single service, you can not apply **multiple** types. `ClusterIP` or `NodePort` you can only use **one**

in a single file what you can do is like

**service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: partner-db
  name: partner-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 1521
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1521
  selector:
    app: partner-db
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: ClusterIP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    app: partner-db
  name: partner-service-node-port
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 1521
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 1521
  selector:
    app: partner-db
  type: NodePort
```

For internal use you can use cluster IP but if you are looking forward to use or expose the service using **Domain** i would suggest you to use ingress.

For this

> app1-->connects to app2(db via ClusterIP: port 1521) app1-->expose to
> ingress to access it from my browser

If you are using the ingress you can use both service type as `ClusterIP` as you want to access your **app1** over browser.

Comment: Can i also use `ClusterIP` for accessing the service over my browser? I have configured ingress to access the service.. I am abel to curl the application with the hostname and prefix i provided. Still it is inside my minikube. The IP is not resolvable outside the minikube, so no access from my browser

Comment: Updating question with my ingress config and the second service I used

Answer (score 2):

You can't define a service with type both `ClusterIP` and `NodePort`.

You need to delete the old service of type `ClusterIP` and create a new one of type `NodePort`.

Remember to keep the `selector` labels in the `Service` spec so that the new service correctly routes the traffic to the right set of pods.

Comment: you can use the `http://service-name.namespace` to connect within the cluster as the services work in layered approach in the sense that a `NodePort` service internally creates a `clusterIP` service and traffic is routed through that. Similarly a `LoadBalancer` service creates both `NodePort` and `ClusterIP` services and the traffic routing happens with `ClusterIP` eventually.

Comment: the type ClusterIp is used to expose the db to the application. If i delete that service then the app will not work

Comment: I believe you can use the NodePort service for exposing db internally as well, just use `service-name` for routing traffics internally and it should work as expected.

Comment: i got the service with clusterIp and Nodeport. But the access to the application still doesnt work